# How to get several proto datastore instances?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, protocol-buffers, datastore, proto

I am trying to migrate my app from shared preferences to proto datastore. Currently I have different shared preferences instances for different users, which I create like this:

```
appContext.getSharedPreferences(userInfo.login, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

Is there a way to achive similar separation in proto datastore?